# Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c++

I am a C++ beginner. I have a c++ project that i built using the existing make files. I have a library that I linked from /usr/local/lib. Build is successful but when I run it, its complaining about the library that I linked form /usr/local/lib. If I copy that library to /lib64 and run my program, everything is fine. Please let me know what I should do to avoid this error. Thank you.

> error while loading shared libraries: libactivemq-cpp.so.14: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: What is the content of your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and its working with out any issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Oli explained, you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but you can also install the library permanently, even if it doesn't live in one of the standard directories.  Start with

```
man ldconfig
```

it's quite important you know how that thing works.

- by default (ie unless you do something) only libraries in the trusted directories (`/lib`  and `/usr/lib`) will be picked up.  I have no running 64 bits system available but i'm guessing on those the directories will be suffixed with 64
- if you want ldconfig to pick up libraries in other dirs, add theses directories to `/etc/ld.so.conf`
- after that, run `ldconfig -v` and check if they actually got picked up

And you'll be all set :-)

Comment: Note that it only worked for me (on Debian Wheezy) running the last command as sudo: `sudo ldconfig`